# (wrong?) proof that $\lim \int f_n d\mu=\int f d\mu$ without a functiong "domintaing" $\vert f_n \vert$

Tags: measure-theory

I proved something that I don't think is true.

> Let $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of measurable functions that converges to $f$. Then if $\mu$ is a finite measure we have $$\lim \int f_n d\mu = \int f d \mu$$

For all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies$ $\vert f_n-f\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)}$. Then

$$\vert \int f_nd\mu - \int f\ d\mu\vert=\vert\int f_n-f \ d\mu\vert\leq\int\vert f_n-f\vert \ d\mu<\int \epsilon/\mu(X)\ d\mu=\epsilon$$
So it follows...

I don't think that is true because this was too easy and we just assumed that $\mu$ is finite... and at the other hand if $\mu$ isn't finite we must have the hypothesis of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem (wich is much hard to prove)...

Is my proof good?

Comment: The proof is ok for the cases it applies. You seem to have assumed that 1) $\mu(X)$ is finite, and 2) the convergence is uniform. You used the latter assumption when concluding that the inequality $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/\mu(X)$ holds **FOR ALL $x\in X$.**

Comment: For comparison, [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) only assumes **pointwise** convergence (a.e.). In that case to a given $\epsilon$ the choice of $N$ depends on the choice of $x$. Your proof does not cover this case, because you assumed more.

Comment: perfect! Thanks

Comment: This may sound like a pedantic commmet, but since you’re asking about the correctedness of your proof, besides of the uniform convergence issue already mentioned, your proof actually fails when $\mu(X)=0$. Of course, that case is trivial but you may want to write a separate line for it.

Comment: thanks everyone! That was exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for